# Problems with frame averaging with Core Image

Tags: avfoundation, metal, ciimage

I'm encountering a very nasty problem in performing a simple frame averaging procedure with Core Image. In summary, I grab frames from the video buffer in the capture output method:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, 
                     didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, 
                     from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    
    guard let cvBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
                return
            }

    let newImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: cvBuffer)

    ...
   
    // Frame averaging part using a CIImageAccumulator
    if (slowIncrement == 0.0) {
                
        accumulator?.setImage(newImage)
                        
        } else {

          makeAverageFiler.currentStack = accumulator?.image()
          makeAverageFiler.newImage = newImage
          makeAverageFiler.count = slowIncrement
          guard let processedImage = makeAverageFiler.outputImage else {return}
                                                
          accumulator?.setImage(processedImage)
                        
          }
       
     slowIncrement += 1.0
     
     ...




}
```

I made a custom filter with the following kernel:

```
float4 makeAverage(sample_t currentStack, sample_t newImage, float stackCount) {
          
          float4 cstack = unpremultiply(currentStack);
          float4 nim = unpremultiply(newImage);
          float4 avg = ((cstack * stackCount) + nim) / (stackCount + 1.0);
          
          return premultiply(avg);
          
      }
```

The algorithm should be correct. When I test the same with a small python snippet on video frames, it works perfectly.
In the app it also works to a point. However, when the app acquires more and more frames, I can see that the colors get messed up and weird color patches start to appear. I suspect that core image is not performing the calculations on the color channels properly, somehow the color channels get clipped.

This is how I initialized the CIImageAccumulator:

```
let accumulator = CIImageAccumulator(extent: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3024, height:  4032), format: .RGBAf)
```

I need to use the accumulator, otherwise, the memory usage grows indefinitely and the app stops working.

I can see that changing the format affects the results. However, I could not find a suitable format that would make the problem disappear.

What am I doing wrong? The cvImageBuffer has a 32bit-per-pixel ARGB pixel format. Is core image performing the conversion to 128bit-per-pixel automatically?

Additional things I tried:

1. unmultiply and premultiply does not seem to fix the results
2. changing the workingformat of the CIContext also does not seem to work. In particular, it seems I can only set the sRGB format as working CIContextOption. Other formats result in raising an exception.

I would really like to avoid using custom metal shaders and stick to core image.
Thanks in advance for your help!

**Update**

Here is an example of the weird patches that start to appear after acquiring for a while. In this case I'm just moving the phone around while capturing. In real world use cases, this problem appears severely when acquiring slow moving clouds.

[image]

**Update 2**

I declare the CIContext as a property of the view controller. Then, I initialize it in viewDidLoad as follow:

```
ciContext = CIContext(mtlDevice: metalView.metalDevice, options: [.workingFormat : CIFormat.RGBAf,
                                                                      .workingColorSpace: NSNull(),
                                                                      .cacheIntermediates : false,
                                                                      .highQualityDownsample: true])
```

I use the ciContext in several places, to both render CIImages on the drawable, create intermediate CGImages and also to save JPEGs. For example, here is the render use:

```
self.ciContext.render(centeredImage,
                          to: currentDrawable.texture,
                          commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
                          bounds: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: view.drawableSize),
                          colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB())
```

Comment: Can you please post an example image that shows the artifacts you are talking about?

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks a lot. I have updated the description to show an example of what is going on. Do you think there could be a problem with accumulator? Or am I messing up with the colorspaces?

Comment: Hmm, strange indeed. I wonder if this is the result of some lack of floating-point precision that is accumulating. How large does your stack grow?

Comment: Mmmm... I was actually suspecting the same! However, this problem arises after only few minutes, definitely before 5 minutes. Considering that I process a max of 30 fps, the stack count would be ~10000. Should not be a problem! I will give a try using a metal shader, somehow I'm beginning to be confused with Core Image and all the magic behind...

Comment: 10000 blending operations is quite a lot.  Maybe you can try to disable ColorSync (color space conversions performed by Core Image) by setting the `workingColorSpace` option of the `CIContext` to `NSNull()`.

Comment: I have implemented a custom metal kernel for doing the same and I encountered the same issue. At this point, at least, I'm almost sure there are problems with: a) gamma encoding/deconding. I can control this with Metal and I can see it makes a difference 2) the floating-point precision of the input/working and output image. I guess something is going wrong in the conversion between 32bit to 8 bit channels. I will try tonight to set the workingspace of the context to NSNull().

Comment: It seems that also setting the workingColorSpace to NSNull() didn't help... I'm losing hope. I'm almost sure the problem arises when CIImage converts back the image to 32RGBA for displaying or saving the picture in JPG.

Answer (score 0):

The default CIContext pixel format is RGBAh, which is 64 bits per pixel. You need RGBAf since you are working with 128 bits per pixel images.
The format needs to be explicitly specified when you create the CIContent like this:

```
let context = CIContext(options: [.workingFormat: CIFormat.RGBAf])
```

This would set the precision for the entire pipeline which would get executed when the image gets rendered.

**UPDATE**

Turns out the "color clipping" issue has nothing to do with the color space conversion or rounding errors. Core Image is doing its calculations just fine.

What is really happening is the "convolution" effect. Due to camera jitter, the neighboring pixels get averaged out with ever diminishing factor, and over time the pixels from earlier frames contribute more and more into the final result. Effectively it's similar to applying a convolution kernel (which size is equal to the average distance of the jitter) with greater values towards one side of the matrix. If there is a color gradient in that direction it gets more pronounced with every iteration.

To confirm that try the following experiment:

1. Take an image (any image)
2. Keep mixing it in a loop with the randomly shifted copy of the original with continuously decreasing factor, accumulating the result.
3. After certain number of iterations (2000 or so) you will start seeing that "convolution" effect. And the more you let it go the more noticeable it'll be.

Here is the code snippet to experiment with:

```
        let shift: CGFloat = 50
        accumulator.setImage(inputImage)
        for i in 0...3000 {
            let xShift = CGFloat.random(in: -shift ... shift)
            let yShift = CGFloat.random(in: -shift ... shift)
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: xShift, y: yShift)
            let shiftedImage = inputImage.transformed(by: transform)
            let factor = Double(i)
            let image = accumulator.image().applyingFilter("CIMix", parameters: [
                kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: shiftedImage,
                kCIInputAmountKey: factor / (factor + 1)
            ]).cropped(to: inputImage.extent)
            accumulator.setImage(image)
        }
```

And here are the results using this image: [image] after 1000, 2000 and 3000 iterations respectively:
[image][image][image]

Now, if you replace the `factor` with a constant number, say `1000` the result will be like this after 3000 iterations:
[image]

You can see some of the color bleeding but not much, since all the pixels are contributing more or less equally creating more of a blur than color gradient effect. If there were any issues with calculations they would have been seen in this case as well.

Comment: I agree that this solution should work and maybe I keep doing something wrong. However, just changing the working format to CIFormat.RGBAf does not seem to fix my problem.

Comment: Yeah that's puzzling. Even though looks like you already have an alternative solution using the Metal and texture, would you mind sharing the code snippet where you set the format to RGBAf and how you use that CIContext?

Comment: Sure, I have updated the questions with the requested code snippets

Comment: @Salvo89 please see my updated answer. Given these findings I can't explain why you don't see he same effect with your metal solution. Probably you have inadvertently changed something in the kernel function or not running it long enough. But everything equal you should see the same result.

Comment: thanks for further looking into the issue. Indeed, the kind of color patches shown in your examples is exactly what is affecting my results. However, for my applications, I cannot keep the factor constant. Furthermore, even in your example with the "factor" kept constant, the level of "color bleeding" is not acceptable. I have tested the metal implementation and it seems to give better results. To be absolutely sure, I might use your exact example, make a comparison one to one and I will post the results here.

Comment: @Salvo89 Sure I am not suggesting to use constant factor. I am just illustrating the point that the color bleeding is due to or exacerbated by the ever diminishing factor value which creates the effect similar to applying the convolution kernel skewed to one side. Would be curious to see your results. This is an interesting issue indeed.

Comment: I haven't had the time to make the comparison one-to-one. However, at this point, I can confidently say that the metal implementation does not present the issue, even for very long exposures. This was also confirmed by all my beta testers. There seem to be some problems with Core Image for this particular case...