# Alpha blending for frame averaging in Core Image

Tags: swift, avfoundation, core-image

In my app, I'm trying to realize a motion blur features that stack different frames (averaging them) coming from the video output into a single image. The effect I'm trying to obtain is well-explained here: https://photographylife.com/image-averaging-technique.

I tried using a custom CIKernel that performs the averaging operation on each color channel as follow:

```
float4 makeAverage(sample_t currentStack, sample_t newImage, float stackCount) {
          
          float4 cstack = unpremultiply(currentStack);
          float4 nim = unpremultiply(newImage);
          float4 avg = ((cstack * stackCount) + nim) / (stackCount + 1.0);
          
          return premultiply(avg);
          
      }
```

You can find more details on the complete code here: [Problems with frame averaging with Core Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045823/problems-with-frame-averaging-with-core-image)

It works but, after a while, weird patches start to appear in the image, hinting that the color channels are clipping.

Is there a way I could achieve the same results using alpha blending in core image? Maybe, instead of doing the stacking operation on the color channels, could I stack subsequent images with a decreasing alpha value?

If so, what would be the procedure/algorithm to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish the same as what you are doing via combination of CIColorMatrix and CISourceOverCompositing in a simpler way just by using CIMix filter like this

```
    func makeCompositeImage(stackImage: CIImage, newImage: CIImage?, count: Double) -> CIImage {
        let opacity = 1.0 / count
        return newImage?
            .applyingFilter("CIMix", parameters: [
                kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: stackImage,
                kCIInputAmountKey: opacity
            ]) ?? stackImage
    }
```

Please check out this app I just published: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/filter-magic/id1594986951. It lets you play with every single filter out there.

Comment: Congratulations for your app! I just downloaded it and it looks great! A nice tool to explore core image filters, definitely needed! Thanks for the tip on the CIMix filter!

Comment: @Salvo89 Thank you! Makes me very happy that you find my app useful. Lots of research and experimentation went into it. Glad to share with the community. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

After some trying, I found the solution. Basically, here is how to achieve the desired effect:

I lower the opacity of each successive frame, using the CIColorMatrix filter. Below the code for the function:

```
func setOpacity (image : CIImage, alpha : Double) ->CIImage {

guard let overlayFilter: CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMatrix") else { fatalError() }
let overlayRgba: [CGFloat] = [0, 0, 0, alpha]
let alphaVector: CIVector = CIVector(values: overlayRgba, count: 4)
overlayFilter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
overlayFilter.setValue(alphaVector, forKey: "inputAVector")

return overlayFilter.outputImage!
```

}

Each time a frame arrives, the alpha value is calculated as 1/count. Then, I perform the alpha blending using the CISourceOverCompositing filter:

```
func makeCompositeImage(stackImage: CIImage?, newImage: CIImage?, count: Double) -> CIImage {
    
    let bgImage = stackImage
    
    let opacity = 1.0 / count
    
    let newImageFiltered = setOpacity(image: newImage!, alpha: opacity)
    // Filter part
    let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISourceOverCompositing")
    currentFilter?.setValue(newImageFiltered, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    currentFilter?.setValue(bgImage, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)
    guard let outputImage = currentFilter?.outputImage else { return bgImage!}
    
    return outputImage
}
```

The method works as expected and I can simulate motion blur from successive frames. However, the original problem remains and after a while, noticeable color bands and patches start to appear in the image, ruining the final results.

I hope, however, that the code above could be useful for somebody.

Comment: "However, the original problem remains and after a while, noticeable color bands and patches start to appear in the image, ruining the final results." Then why is this an answer to the question?

Comment: Because the question was specifically on how to do alpha blending for frame averaging in Core Image. As I wrote here: "Is there a way I could achieve the same results using alpha blending in core image?" and here: "If so, what would be the procedure/algorithm to do it?" and in the title. The code allows you to do alpha blending to achieve motion blur, so I think it can be useful for somebody.